# What is the pdf of $X$, where $dX_t = -aX_t + d N_t, N_t$ is a compound Poisson process?

Tags: probability-distributions, random-variables, stochastic-calculus, markov-process, poisson-distribution

I would like to find the probability density function (at stationarity) of the random variable $X_t$, where (I'm not sure this notation makes sense, I'm not very familiar with the stochastic calculus literature):
\begin{equation*}
dX_t = -aX_t + d N_t,
\end{equation*}
$a$ is a constant and $N_t$ is a compound Poisson process with Poisson jump size distribution.

In other words, $X_t$ solves the ordinary differential equation 
$\frac{d X_t}{dt} + a X_t=0$, 
but at times $t_i$ say, where the $t_i$ are exponentially distributed with mean $1/k$, $X_t$ increases by an integer drawn from $M\sim Poi(m)$ (i.e. $X_t$ gets a Poisson-distributed "kick" upwards at exponentially distributed intervals).

Is there a way of obtaining the pdf for this random variable $X$? If I have understood things correctly, the Kramers-Moyal equation for the pdf of $X$ is of infinite order because it is a jump Markov process. I have also tried looking at the Master Equation but I get lost. However, I am new to this literature and was wondering if the solution is easy for those in the know, since it is such a simple system.

Many thanks for your help!